# Android: Share event from default Calendar to my app

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types, intentfilter

Similar to sharing images/audio and plain text, I want to see my app when user shares event from default calendar app.

I am sure there is something to do with mime type.

As I see my app in list that shares images, similar to that I would like to see my app when an event is shared.

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/event" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

update,I am able to show my app in event sharing intent now using code below

```
   <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

So, Working on similar lines what I was thinking changing to `*/*`did the trick but its still not done as I need only for sharing events not images/videos/audios/text  etc.

just need some mimetype that can support all types of events

Comment: have u tried this <data android:host="com.android.calendar"/>

Comment: @AndoMasahashi thanks for your reply, I havent tried this yet, I will just try this now

Comment: @AndoMasahashi didnt help, I was still able to see my app on photo sharing intent

Comment: try this now <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/event" />

Answer (score 0):

Perfect!!

I was able to fix this, posting my answer here, so that anyone can use my solution in future

I was able to do this using `text/x-vcalenda`

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcalendar" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Maybe this is new in 7.0 (Nougat) but it took me a while to figure out that the mimeType is actually `text/x-vCalendar` with a capital C. Using your version does not work (for me at least).